# How to access hierarchical information of nodes in the ontology to assign different weights to classes at different levels?

Tags: python, hierarchy, ontology, taxonomy, owlready

I want to get subclasses of a specific ontology class but not in a random way, I am looking for a way to get them by their hierarchical levels: I mean showing for each class of the ontology its subclasses along with their hierarchical information(such as level or depth in the ontology); is it possible in python, knowing that I'm using owlready2. So far, I am able to get the list of subclasses of a specific class using owlready2 but it returns a list and ignores the position of subclass in ontology, but I want to get access to the hierarchical information of those subclasses as well so that I can assign higher weights to subclasses at a higher level of ontology and lower weights to the subclasses at the lower level(more depth) in the ontology. Is there any method, package or tool available which I can use to do so in python. Any help will be highly appreciated since I am new to python and this task.